# XPath request to select all 'a' elements

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to write an Xpath request to select all 'a' elements into a div with id=mw-bodyContent. But, into this big div I need to forget an other one with the class atributes = to "navbox-group". I tried this request but this desperately do not work :) :

```
//div[@id="bodyContent"]/div[not(contains(@class,"navbox_group"))]//a[not(contains(@class,"nofollow")) and not(contains(@class,"extiw"))]
```

Comment: It's a typo? ' //a[ '    Mayby need this ' /a[ '  ?

Comment: if I put just '/a[' he don't give me all the link in the bodyContent div (only 3 when there are more than 600...)

Comment: if this can help this a a request to download all link from a wikipedia aticle page (except the div with the id=navbox_group of course)

Comment: For example there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matth%C3%A4us_Schwarz is 84 links.  You can test your xpath in chrome.

Comment: With Chrome I found the Xpath of just the div i don't want to have in the request :
              //*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div[@class="navbox_group"]

but now i don't know how to put this into the principal request...

Comment: @Gregsparrow unfortunately, your page does not have a "navbox_group" div :) visually, this div correspond to the blue box with a list of general links in the bottom of the article, for instance here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism

Comment: I dont found navbox_group in this article either

Comment: in the english wiki it is a table with the class "navbox", i need french wiki. my test page is : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%C3%A9_d%27Aix-Marseille

Comment: Ok,  check this //a[not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,"navbox_group")])]. It is select all 'a' nodes exclude in  navbox div

Comment: this seems to work ideally, thank you very much, i was ignoring the "ancestor" thing here :)

I don't have enough reputation to pass this from a discussion into a chat aand credit you for the answer, can you do that ?

Comment: @LéoJoubert you should post a sample input XML and the expected output, perhaps. It is always better to get good understanding of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand you want to fetch all **a** nodes and exclude in *navbox_group* div. This will help you `//a[not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,"navbox_group")])]`

That would search for all **a** nodes where ancestor not a *navbox_group*